# Problem on limit of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I got stuck on a problem recently which apparently leads to bizarre conclusions..

Let $a_1=1$, and $a_n=n(a_{n-1}+1)$ for all $n={2,3,...}$
Define $$P(n)=\Biggl(1+\frac{1}{a_1}\Biggl)\Biggl(1+\frac{1}{a_2}\Biggl)...\Biggl(1+\frac{1}{a_n}\Biggl)$$

Compute: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}P(n)$$
The way I did it was..i simplified $P(n)$ to get $P(n)=\frac{a_{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$

Now, rearranging the expression I got $$\frac{1}{n}=\frac{a_{n-1}+1}{a_n}$$
Let $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\Delta$, then taking the limit as n$\to\infty$ of the above expression gives $0=\frac{\Delta+1}{\Delta}$ leading to $\Delta=-1$ but clearly, $\{a_n\}$ is an increasing sequence..where am I wrong?

This line of reasoning also leads to the required limit being 0..which again is obviously wrong..

Edit:I want to know what's wrong in what I've done..and I haven't seen this approach elsewhere. I know there are solutions to this already on this website..but the approach there is different..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $a_1=1$ and $a_n=n(a_{n-1}+1)$ for $n=2,3,...$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3552895/let-a-1-1-and-a-n-na-n-11-for-n-2-3)

Comment: No..I've seen that before..I wanted to know what's wrong in my understanding..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a_n >n$ for all $n$ so $a_n$ does not converge to a finite limit $\Delta$. Your mistake is in assuming that $\Delta$ is finite.

Comment: okay..but don't we assume the limit to be some number say alpha and continue in most problems?

Comment: @binarybitarray, you first have to prove it is convergent first.

Comment: Okay, if possible can you give links to an example problem so that I understand it better?

Comment: Example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3552900/show-that-lim-n-to-infty-x-n-exists-and-find-it